# how to check condition in xml response in jmeter

Tags: xml, jmeter

In jmeter ,In a xml response with multiple same name's tag, I want to validate that in case value of tag onlineFulfilmentFlag is Y ,then productId should not be blank.In case of failure of above  condition , I want to print a failure message as" INVALID PRODUCT ID" .I am also attaching  the response .This code contain description of 1 offer ,but this number can vary from 0-10.

```
enter code here<offers>
       <number xsi:nil="true"/>
       <number>
          <amrit>S</amrit>
          <interestedFlag>Y</interestedFlag>
          <msgid>145983</msgid>
          <msisdn xsi:nil="true"/>                 
          <offerIndex>1</offerIndex>
          <msgtext>Rs115=225 </msgtext>
          <onlineFulfilmentFlag>Y</onlineFulfilmentFlag>
          <orderId xsi:nil="true"/>
          <otherSearchInfo>
             <number>
                <key>START_DATE</key>
                <value>2016-09-16 11:28:46.921455</value>
             </number>
             <number>
                <key>END_DATE</key>
                <value>2017-08-03 00:00:00.0</value>
             </number>
             <number>
                <key>OFFER_CATEGORY</key>
                <value>Others</value>
             </number>
          </otherSearchInfo>
          <price>115</price>
          <productId>ACT3G</productId>
          <shortDesc>115=225Loc+STD M,28D</shortDesc>
          <subscriptionStatus>P</subscriptionStatus>
       </number>
       <number>
          <amrit>O</amrit>
          <interestedFlag>Y</interestedFlag>
          <msgid>143429</msgid>
          <msisdn xsi:nil="true"/>
          <msgid>2803708</msgid>
          <offerIndex>2</offerIndex>
          <msgtext>Rs306=Rs306 Full</msgtext>
          <onlineFulfilmentFlag>Y</onlineFulfilmentFlag>
          <orderId xsi:nil="true"/>
          <otherSearchInfo>
             <number>
                <key>START_DATE</key>
                <value>2016-09-16 11:28:46.921455</value>
             </number>
             <number>
                <key>END_DATE</key>
                <value>2017-08-03 00:00:00.0</value>
             </number>
             <number>
                <key>OFFER_CATEGORY</key>
                <value>Combo</value>
             </number>
          </otherSearchInfo>
          <price>306</price>
          <productId>ACT3G</productId>
          <shortDesc>Rs306=306TT(Ultd Val)</shortDesc>
          <subscriptionStatus>P</subscriptionStatus>
       </number>
       <number>
          <amrit>O</amrit>
          <interestedFlag>Y</interestedFlag>
          <msgid>145022</msgid>
          <msisdn xsi:nil="true"/>
          <msgid>2800482</msgid>
          <msgtext>Rs110=Rs110 Full</msgtext>
          <onlineFulfilmentFlag>Y</onlineFulfilmentFlag>
          <orderId xsi:nil="true"/>
          <otherSearchInfo>
             <number>
                <key>START_DATE</key>
                <value>2016-09-16 11:28:46.921455</value>
             </number>
             <number>
                <key>END_DATE</key>
                <value>2017-08-03 00:00:00.0</value>
             </number>
             <number>
                <key>OFFER_CATEGORY</key>
                <value>Others</value>
             </number>
          </otherSearchInfo>
          <price>110</price>
          <productId>ACT3G</productId>
          <shortDesc>Rs110=Rs110 FTT, ULTD</shortDesc>
          <subscriptionStatus>P</subscriptionStatus>
       </number>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `//number/onlineFulfilmentFlag='Y' and string-length(//number/productId) > 0` should do the trick.

You can put the above expression (or amend it as per your requirements) into the [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) and if `productId` field length will be zero (or it will not be present) the sampler will automatically get failed.

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)